# How to get table values when check box will checked using Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a table with data including one check-box in each row.I need when user will click on check box then the corresponding row values will retrieve using Rails.My table is given below.

> paymentdetails.html.erb:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <colgroup>
            <col class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
            <col class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
            <col class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <col class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <col class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center"><input type="checkbox"></th>
                <th class="text-center">Sl. No</th>
                <th class="text-center">Date</th>
                <th class="text-center">Receipt No.</th>
                <th class="text-center">Amount</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% @result.each do |r| %>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center"><%= check_box_tag :check_value,:value => r  %></th>
                <td class="text-center"><%= r.id %></td>
                <td class="text-center"><%= r.c_date %></td>
                <td class="text-center"><%= r.Receipt_No %></td>
                <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i><%= r.v_amount %></td>
            </tr>
            <% end %>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

> payment_controller.rb:

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController

    def payment
        @payment=Vendor.new
        @add_payment=AddPayment.new
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html 
            format.js
        end

    end
    def check_type  
        if params[:commit]=="submit"
            @vendor_type = PaymentVendor.where(:v_name => params[:v_name]).map{|v|[v.v_catagory ,v.Receipt_No]}
            #@vendor_type = PaymentVendor.where(:v_name => params[:v_name]).pluck(:v_catagory)
            output=[]
            @result=[]
            @vendor_type.each do |i|
              if i.first == params[:payment][:s_catagory]
                output << i[1]
              end  
            end  
            output.each_with_index{|val, index|
               #puts "#{val} => #{index}" 
               #puts output1[index]
               @result << PaymentVendor.find_by_Receipt_No(output[index])


            }
        else
            @v_name=Vendor.where(:s_catagory => params[:payment][:s_catagory] ).pluck(:v_name)
        end
    end
    def add_payment
        if params[:commit]
        else
            if params[:add_payment][:p_catagory]=="Cheque"

            end
        end
    end
end
```

When check box will checked the row all row value will fetch to controller action assign to a variable.Similarly for multiple check box if at a time all check box will select all row values corresponding to each check box will assign to a variable.Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Although this is not an answer to your question, please notice that all your checkboxes have the same `id` (`"checkbox1-1"`). You might want to change that, as it could cause issues later on. ID's should be unique.

Comment: @Myst : Now Do you have any solution for this ?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is writing an [AJAX request](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) (using the `onclick` javascript callback), to send the information. But this might limit the use of the web app to javascript enabled devices and also my javascript isn't very strong. I hope someone else comes up with a better solution.

Comment: @ Myst :Canyou help me for this problem.I have a generated html input filed is like this <input id="r_value" name="r_value" type="hidden" value="{:value=>150325006}">.Can you tell me how can i access the field value in controller page.